# Using the contents of a file while using Spawn Child Process

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process, spawn

I am having some trouble properly using the spawn child process function in a node.js Electron application.

When I type the following command into my terminal, everything works as expected:

```
AtomicParsley 'filePath' --rDNSatom "$(cat /tmp/xmlMOVI.txt)" name=iTunMOVI domain=com.apple.iTunes
```

This changes the iTunMOVI atom in the metadata of an mp4 file to the contents of my temp text file. However, when I run this:

```
var cmd = 'AtomicParsley 'filePath' --rDNSatom "$(cat /tmp/xmlMOVI.txt)" name=iTunMOVI domain=com.apple.iTunes
spawn('AtomicParsley', arguments);
```

the resulting mp4 file has the string '$(cat /tmp/xmlMOVI.txt)' instead of the contents of the file. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already looked into/tried using Child Process's [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)?

Comment: Hi Theo, is your example code what you are actually using? It doesn't look like it would compile and I'm not seeing where `arguments` is defined. The most likely problem is that `AtomicParsely` isn't accessible in the application's PATH, or you are passing string `arguments` where you should be passing array `arguments`

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. @RobM you are right, there was a mistake in the code I put up there. However, the real bug was that the spawn couldn't do another command (the cat) so I ended up running the spawn inside another spawned process, which allowed me to pipe the stdout of the cat into the newly spawned process. Thanks!